# How do I change my table's identity column datatype without losing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

The database that I am tasked with fixing has a table with an identity column/PK that has a datatype of BigInt.  This causes problem with the Access front end in that a datasheet to this linked table will not allow edits to the records.  (This is a known issue with ODBC drivers and Access)

The table's Id column should never have been created as a bigint in the first place but that is a moot point now. I need to convert or recreate this column with a datatype of int, without losing the existing data.

There are ~2 million records in this table.
There are an unknown number of apps and Access apps that access this table so I am trying to do this as smoothly/stealthily as possible since the likelihood of finding all of those apps and modifying them before I make the change is slim.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: It's fairly straight-forward in Sql Server, not sure what you have to do to keep the metadata in-synch for Access though.

Comment: I'm not worried about the Access metadata. Everything I try in SQL tells me that I have to drop and recreate the table

Comment: You do, but that can be done without losing any data. Its fairly easy from the GUI (Management Studio).  If you need a SQL Script, then it's easiest to let the GUI make it for you.

Comment: This is a bad idea for a poor reason.  Simply don't attempt to display the ID column in Access.  You probably can't edit it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it from Management Studio(SSMS):

1. First, make a backup copy of your database.  If you make a mistake, or something unexpected happens, the easiest way to fix it is to restore from backup.
2. In the SSMS Explorer Pane, navigate to the table, then right-click on it and click "Design".
3. Select the Identity column's row and change it's datatype to "INT".
4. Save your changes, ignore the warning.

If you need a script instead, then replace step (4) above with:

- Click the Script Changes button. Ignore the warning and then copy the script into you paste buffer.  Make a new query window and paste the script into it.  Then close the design window, cancelling any changes.

---

As Stuart Ainsworth points out, in later versions of SQL Server, it may prevent you from doing this, with a warning about "Dropping a Table".  To fix this in SSMS, click the Tools..Options menu entry, then go to the "Tables and Designers" pane under "Designers" and uncheck the "Prevent saving changes that require table recreation" option.

Comment: This assumes a couple of things; 1: SSMS must be configured to allow making changes that will drop data (that's a new option), and 2: you've got time and space to move 2 million rows of data into a temporary table.

Comment: 2 million? That is like asking "you need storage space for a5 usd bill". 2 million rows you can stora on any hard mobile phone unless this is an image heavy column.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth This particular procedure has worked for me since SQL Server 2005.  AFAIK, the "Allow Drop" option actually used to be the default behaivior, and only after they made it configurable did the default change to disallowing it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I believe that's true, and it's easy to switch it off, but I think the default behavior is now "DON'T DROP".  If you don't specify, then the OP would be left trying to figure out why this error occurred.

Comment: @TomTom Sure, any modern server should be able to handle an additional 2 million rows, but you have to admit that it comes with SOME cost, and without knowing what the capacity/specs are that are powering the server, then it's assumption that should be clarified.  My assumption is that if you're using Access as a front end, you probably haven't invested much in your infrastructure (again, an assumption) :)

Comment: @StuartAinsworth OK, I've added a note about it.

Comment: and I +1'd your answer :)  Definitely the easiest way to go; I just always worry about dropping tables in production :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the IDENTITY column is your PRIMARY KEY, and it's probably clustered :)  MY advice below is based on those assumptions.

If you've only got a few indexes on the table, and the PRIMARY KEY is only referenced by a few FOREIGN keys, you should be able to change the datatype by:

1. Dropping any nonclustered indexes which contain the IDENTITY value.
2. Dropping the FOREIGN KEY constraints which point to the PRIMARY KEY.
3. Drop the PRIMARY KEY
4. `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname INT;`
5. REcreate the PRIMARY KEY
6. Re-enable the FOREIGN KEY constraints with CHECK.
7. Recreate your nonclustered indexes.

As RBarryYoung pointed out, a lot of this can be scripted out by the SSMS GUI (if it's configured to allow saving changes), but the difference is that the GUI will create a temporary table, move your data, rename the new table to the old name, and drop the original.

Comment: I have compared these two approaches in the past and (surprisingly) didn't find much difference in performance.  Apparently the `ALTER TABLE..ALTER COLUMN..` command does some kind of extensive rebuild of the table under the hood (at least when its the clustered key, the only case I actually tested).